# Renaming Sentinel Image folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, sentinel-2

I am using Sentinel 2 images downloaded from  https://scihub.copernicus.eu

Image downloaded as zipped folder has very large file and folder names.
Example 'S2A_MSIL1C_20220405T063631_N0400_R120_T40QDG_20220405T073739.SAFE' folder has a file 'MTD_MSIL1C.xml'

When I renamed folder from 'S2A_MSIL1C_20220405T063631_N0400_R120_T40QDG_20220405T073739.SAFE' to 'Img4' the icon of 'MTD_MSIL1C.xml' changed to xml. Now when I add it in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro it gives me error.

What is the proper way to rename folder?

I even tried updating the XML files replacing the old folder name with new one.

[image]

Following is the error I am getting in ArcGIS Pro:

[image]

Following error comes when I tried to load from renamed folder in ArcMap:

[image]

Comment: Basically i have to move data to a new location and i am getting errors like large file names, so this is why i am thinking to rename it

Comment: I think it's just ArcGIS following the spec rigidly. If I rename the folder, QGIS can read it.

Comment: What is the error that ArcGIS gives you when you try and read it with the shorter folder name?

Comment: Updated the question with error images

Comment: Error messages should always be included as text in the body of the Question. This makes them legible on all devices and searchable by others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The folder name appears once in each of the top-level XML files:

```
INSPIRE.xml:                        
<gco:CharacterString>
S2A_MSIL1C_20220418T050701_N0400_R019_T43MBP_20220418T074418.SAFE
</gco:CharacterString>

MTD_MSIL1C.xml:
<PRODUCT_URI>
S2A_MSIL1C_20220418T050701_N0400_R019_T43MBP_20220418T074418.SAFE
</PRODUCT_URI>
```

It may be that the program detects a mismatch and throws an error in case the data has been misplaced. Try editing the XML files to your new shorter name and see if that works.

The GDAL driver doesn't mention anything about this, but also says you can open the ZIP file itself without having to unzip it, so maybe that works for you.

https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/sentinel2.html

The gdal command line tools seem okay with renaming the folder, so maybe ArcGIS is being extra vigilant, but I'm surprised it doesn't simply trust GDAL for this.

Comment: I did that but it is the same, there were four places where old file name was used. 

UserProduct_index.html, INSPIRE.xml, MTD_MSIL1C.xml, Multispectral_MTD_MSIL1C.afrx.xml (two places)